# Best way to handle unique ids

Tags: solidity, arrays

A `msg.sender` can create multiple Struct `Item` . What would be best way to store the `Item` ?

Currently I'm using

```
struct Item {
    uint256 amt;
    bool isActive;
    address owner;
}
Item[] public items;
function createItem(uint amt) returns(uint a){
   items.push(Item({
      ...
   }))
   return (items.length);
}
```

But `createItem` returns a `tx` hash as it's not mined yet.

Calling a `items.length` after mining completes won't guarantee me the `id`.

I also tried adding it in mapping but mapping don't accept Struct Arrays

```
Item[] public itemStack;
mapping(address => itemStack) public items; //TypeError: Name has to refer to a struct, enum or contract.
...
items[msg.sender].push(...)
```

Comment: I think your second version should be `mapping(address => Item[])`, right? For your first question, you pretty much have to log an event and check the transaction receipt for that event. (Last I checked, this was *not* straightforward in web3.js.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an event/log to get return values from non-constant functions which is a bit involved but you can check [here in the doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events) for a description.

In your case you will need to declare an event such as `event LogItemCreated(address indexed sender, uint itemId);` in the global context where your global/storage vars are declared. Then before the return statement in `createItem()` do `LogItemCreated(msg.sender, items.length);`.

Then in your tests or however you're calling the contract you need to listen for that event. I do this with this JS function which you can paste into node or a truffle test file.

```
const listenForEvent = event => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    event.watch((error, response) => {
        if (!error) {
            resolve(response.args)
        } else {
            reject(error)
        }
        event.stopWatching()
    })
})
```

Then in node or your test file do this before or directly after doing the transaction `listenForEvent(contractInstance.LogItemCreated({sender: txSenderAddress})`. Where `contractInstance` is the contract you're making the transaction on and `txSenderAddress` is the address of the account that made the transaction to `createItem()`. This should return the item id as expected.

It's a bit long winded but it's worth learning about events since they're the only way to get return values from non-constant functions.